# Is it not possible to open the git bash from the Windows Run window?

Tags: git, git-bash

When I try to open the git bash from the Windows Run window, it opens and instantly closes again. It works perfectly fine when I search and run it with the run icon. I can also open the bash via the cmd with git-bash.exe and with the right-click selection menu.

If I cant fix, its not a problem. I just find it weird

Comment: `git-bash` is not typically installed on your PATH when you install Git for Windows. `bash` probably is, but that's not a terminal, it's an executable that needs to be run in a terminal. If I type all of `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` in my Windows Run window, then I get an actual Git Bash window. If you look at the properties of the working Git Bash icon, it should provide that full path as the target.

Comment: Yeah thats it. Thanks